# How can I convert a number to its multiple form in Perl?

Tags: perl, format, numbers

Do you know an easy and straight-forward method/sub/module which allows me to convert a number (say 1234567.89) to an easily readable form - something like 1.23M?

Right now I can do this by making several comparisons, but I'm not happy with my method:

```
if($bytes > 1000000000){ 
   $bytes = ( sprintf( "%0.2f", $bytes/1000000000 )). " Gb/s";                   
}
elsif ($bytes > 1000000){       
   $bytes = ( sprintf( "%0.2f", $bytes/1000000 )). " Mb/s"; 
}
elsif ($bytes > 1000){
   $bytes = ( sprintf( "%0.2f", $bytes/1000 )). " Kb/s"; 
}
else{ 
   $bytes = sprintf( "%0.2f", $bytes ). "b/s";
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [Number::Bytes::Human](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Number-Bytes-Human) module should be able to help you out.

An example of how to use it can be found in its synopsis:

```
  use Number::Bytes::Human qw(format_bytes);

  $size = format_bytes(0); # '0'
  $size = format_bytes(2*1024); # '2.0K'

  $size = format_bytes(1_234_890, bs => 1000); # '1.3M'
  $size = format_bytes(1E9, bs => 1000); # '1.0G'

  # the OO way
  $human = Number::Bytes::Human->new(bs => 1000, si => 1);
  $size = $human->format(1E7); # '10MB'
  $human->set_options(zero => '-');
  $size = $human->format(0); # '-'
```

Answer (score 3):

[Number::Bytes::Human](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Number::Bytes::Human) seems to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

In pure Perl form, I've done this with a nested ternary operator to cut on verbosity:

```
sub BytesToReadableString($) {
   my $c = shift;
   $c >= 1073741824 ? sprintf("%0.2fGB", $c/1073741824)
      : $c >= 1048576 ? sprintf("%0.2fMB", $c/1048576)
      : $c >= 1024 ? sprintf("%0.2fKB", $c/1024)
      : $c . "bytes";
}

print BytesToReadableString(225939) . "/s\n";
```

Outputs:

```
220.64KB/s
```

Comment: What's with the superfluous scalar($c)?

Comment: The scalar function is a typecasts.  It's an easy way to convert an integer to a string.  It also removes ambiguity between text and numeric operations.

Comment: Perl doesn't typecast at all. Any string operation, such as the concatenation operator, will turn it into a string for you.

Comment: Looking back, I think you're both right.  I've removed it for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

```
sub magnitudeformat {
  my $val = shift;
  my $expstr;

  my $exp = log($val) / log(10);
     if ($exp < 3)  { return $val;   }
  elsif ($exp < 6)  { $exp = 3;  $expstr = "K"; }
  elsif ($exp < 9)  { $exp = 6;  $expstr = "M"; }
  elsif ($exp < 12) { $exp = 9;  $expstr = "G"; } # Or "B".
  else              { $exp = 12; $expstr = "T"; }

  return sprintf("%0.1f%s", $val/(10**$exp), $expstr);
}
```

Comment: Why stop at T?  P, E, Z, Y, X, W, V, U, TD, S, R, Q, PP, O, N, MI, and L follow (though only through Y are they "official").

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is in PHP, and it's loosely based on some example someone else had on their website somewhere (sorry buddy, I can't remember).

The basic concept is instead of using if, use a loop.

```
function formatNumberThousands($a,$dig)
{
    $unim = array("","k","m","g");
    $c = 0;
    while ($a>=1000 && $c<=3) {
        $c++;
        $a = $a/1000;
    }
    $d = $dig-ceil(log10($a));
    return number_format($a,($c ? $d : 0))."".$unim[$c];
}
```

The number_format() call is a PHP library function which returns a string with commas between the thousands groups. I'm not sure if something like it exists in perl.

The $dig parameter sets a limit on the number of digits to show. If $dig is 2, it will give you 1.2k from 1237.

To format bytes, just divide by 1024 instead.

This function is in use in some production code to this day.

Comment: The poster asked about Perl, not PHP. PHP code won't help him.